# jquery if statement on click element (simple slider)

Tags: jquery, if-statement, slider

Making a very simple slider, and this was the method I was taking. With this code when you click the right arrow, for the next slide, the first time, it works great. The problem is the right arrow dies after that.

```
if ($('.slide1').hasClass('active-slide')) {
    $('.right-arrow').click(function () {
         <--! Changes to Slide 2 -->
    });
}

if ($('.slide2').hasClass('active-slide')) {
    $('.right-arrow').click(function () {
         <--! Changes to Slide 3 -->
    });
}

if ($('.slide3').hasClass('active-slide')) {
    $('.right-arrow').click(function () {
         <--! Changes to Slide 4 -->
    });
}
```

etc....

Comment: Your if statements are only being executed once, so the click is always bound to the handler that switches 1 to 2. You need to reverse it: Have one click handler, and put your if statements and slide-switching logic in there.

Comment: Think of a different approach, you are registering the same click event three times or as many slides you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem here on SO. You need to re-think how you're doing these bindings:

```
$('.right-arrow').click(function () {
    if ($('.slide1').hasClass('active-slide')) {
        //...
    }
});
```

If you want to make it more dynamic, consider something like this:

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x3K42/)</kbd>

```
$('.right-arrow').click(function() {
    var $active = $('.active-slide');
    var $next = $('.active-slide').next('.slide');
    if ($next.length == 0) $next = $('.slide:first');
    $active.removeClass('active-slide');
    $next.addClass('active-slide');
});
```